# powershell Set key in System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512

Tags: powershell, azure, encryption, hmac

I have the code below:

```
# Powershell HMAC SHA 256

$message = 'Message'
$secret = 'secret'

$hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512

$hmacsha.key = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($secret)


$signature = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($message))
$signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($signature)

echo $signature

# Do we get the expected signature?
echo ($signature -eq 'z12KOCXYQjCZyKf6WP+yYBONCS+IwNuv9oPbRcL4u+WetE4BvAm1Ysy+bEyGxq/QDLAufO0sPnVLUl/ubvPGdQ==')
```

When i run this code on my computer, it works fine.
My issue is when i try to run it in my Azure environment. Azure don't like the syntax "$hmacsha.key = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($secret)"

This is the error im getting when i try to publish the code:

> An error occured while publishing the runbook 'HiBob'. Error details:
>   BadRequest: The Runbook definition is invalid. This type of assignment
>   is not supported. Only variable names (i.e.: $variable) may be used as
>   the target of an assignment statement..

basically I cant set this array column "key" using the  " $hmacsha.key = "
method.

Anyone has a different idea to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of PS is being run in both environments? 
Also, use Get-Module to see what is being used in each environment.

Comment: `$Key = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($secret); $hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512 (,$Key)` might do it.

Comment: Otherwise try to use the `Key` property setter `$hmacsha.set_Key([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($secret))`

Comment: that worked!
Thank you very much.
Might explain what did you do?